# What are the Instagram BETA Protocols/URIs for posting?

Tags: windows-phone-8, instagram

So I'm trying to deep link from an app into the Instagram BETA app on Windows Phone. And it's not going well.

First, does anyone know the URI for posting?

Second, when I use the URI "instagram://" it looks to be loading the app, and then bounces back to my app, so I think I'm on the right track. Any chance there is something in the Framework to discover the protocols? I'm sure that the phone has to collect this to deal with URIs with specific file types.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sheme "instagram".

Information from [325 Windows Phone apps you can launch from your own app](http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2014/03/325-windows-phone-apps-you-can-launch.html)